# Conditional protocol conformance?

Tags: swift, generics, constraints, protocols

I want to do something like this:

```
class SomeClass<Element> { }
extension SomeClass: SomeProtocol where Element: String { }
```

It tells me:

> Extension of type "SomeClass" with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause.

I could have sworn up to this point that this was one of the bread and butter features of the protocol/extension/generic/associatedtype paradigm. Is there another way to implement this?

Comment: No that is not possible at present. That is the reason why Array does not conform to Equatable even if its elements are Equatable.

Comment: There is an accepted proposal to implement this in the next swift version: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md

Comment: This is coming in Swift 4.1!  https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was implemented in Swift 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul, you can now do it in Swift 4

```
protocol Nameable {
    var name:String {get set}
}
func createdFormattedName<T:Nameable>(_ namedEntity:T) -> String where T:Equatable {
    //Only entities that conform to Nameable which also conform to equatable can call this function
    return "This things name is " + namedEntity.name
}
```